# What's your 'no framework' Java framework?

Tags: java, frameworks

**DISCLAIMER:** The title is taken from a similar question on PHP - [What's your 'no framework' PHP framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/694929/851432). I liked that post and search around Stackoverflow to find something like that, but I can't. That is why I am having a post here. And when I typed the title I got a warning - *The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.* I don't want it to be subjective, and that is not my intention.

---

We all get to work with many projects. They can be of any size, from small to large ones. We also need to work with frameworks to reduce our development time and efforts. But, at times, choosing the right framework is became a burden, especially for small applications. We don't want to put a large framework into action on small projects, because they usually prove to be expensive. Many of us may prefer small, minimal and personal set of libraries.

So my question is same as the one from the inspirational question. I am copy-pasting that here with modification for Java. I am more interested in Web applications.

**What is your method when it comes to 'rolling your own' framework for Java applications, and how does it vary depending on the type/scope of a project?**

**What does your code look like for a typical page? What is your file structure? What 3rd party libraries/components do you commonly use, and how do you keep your libraries, classes organized?**

Do you address/implement:

```
DB abstraction
REST
OOP
MVC
```

and if so, how?

At what point do you consider using a more popular, existing framework (eg. Spring) instead?

Comment: i always use spring, even for small projects. First of all its not heavyweight. It's really easy to setup. The spring code is smaller than anything you'd roll on your own. And, you usually don't know up front how big a "small" project might grow to down the line. So what you're suggesting is simply a bad idea, at least in the web framework space. It's too bad this was closed. I could have racked up some easy rep points on this.